# dynamically joining tables of different counts SAS

Tags: sql, dynamic, sas, join

im working in sas sql.

I have a script that always generates a different number of tables according to the time interval. For each day one table, names of columns are the same except column  balance. This column name contains date. Name of table is TableName_date like TableName_07092017 ... TableName_31092017

```
MT          column      RT  AREA balance_07092017 
ACCOUNTS    balance_lcy 30      2004862772  
ACCOUNTS    balance_lcy 30  CA  121390255,8 
ACCOUNTS    balance_lcy 30  GL  323499587
ACCOUNTS    balance_lcy 30  TF  -7821721555 
C_ACCOUNTS  balance_lcy 35  CA  2,49733E+11 
C_ACCOUNTS  balance_lcy 35  NO  3748192715  


 MT         column      RT  AREA balance_08092017 
 ACCOUNTS   balance_lcy 30      -24278162321    
 ACCOUNTS   balance_lcy 30  CA  225363070.05    
 ACCOUNTS   balance_lcy 30  GL  3117815863.7
 ACCOUNTS   balance_lcy 30  TF  47914289803 
 C_ACCOUNTS balance_lcy 35  CA  37637391174 
 C_ACCOUNTS balance_lcy 35  NO  163722935.2
```

is it possible to create a script that would automatically join these tables? They should look like this

```
MT          column      RT  AREA balance_07092017 balance_08092017 balance_09092017 balance_10092017....
ACCOUNTS    balance_lcy 30      2004862772        -24278162321
ACCOUNTS    balance_lcy 30  CA  121390255,8       225363070.05
ACCOUNTS    balance_lcy 30  GL  323499587         3117815863.7
ACCOUNTS    balance_lcy 30  TF  -7821721555       47914289803
C_ACCOUNTS  balance_lcy 35  CA  2,49733E+11       37637391174
C_ACCOUNTS  balance_lcy 35  NO  3748192715        163722935.2
```

here is the code that creates the tables that I need to join

```
%macro sqlloop(start,end); 
   PROC SQL; 
     %DO DT_REP=&start. %TO &end.; 

        %let year=%sysfunc(year(&DT_REP.));
        %let month=%sysfunc(month(&DT_REP.));
        %let month1=%sysfunc(PUTN(&month.,z2.));
        %let day=%sysfunc(day(&DT_REP.));
        %let day1=%sysfunc(PUTN(&day.,z2.));
        %let datum= &day1.&month1.&year.;
        %put &datum.;

       CREATE TABLE DUPLICITY_BAL_&datum. as 
        select 'ACCOUNTS' as MT, 'balance_lcy' as column, rec_type, area, sum(balance_lcy) as balance_lcy, count(balance_lcy) as count
        from database.ACCOUNTS
        where version_no = 1
          and dt_rep = &DT_REP.
        group by rec_type, area

        union all
        select 'C_ACCOUNTS' as MT, 'balance_lcy' as column, rec_type, area, sum(balance_lcy) as balance_lcy, count(balance_lcy) as count
        from database.C_ACCOUNTS
        where version_no = 1
          and dt_rep = &DT_REP.
        group by rec_type, area;
     %END; 
   QUIT;
%mend; 

%sqlloop(start=21070, end=21073)
```

Comment: You should post what code you have tried so far.  This seems a simple task just by merging the tables together on MT, column, RT and AREA.  I'd be tempted to create a view rather than a table, just to avoid duplication of data storage.

Comment: "is it possible to create a script that would automatically join these tables?" Yes it is. Please make sure your questions are actually the question you want answered, ie how do I create a script that would join these tables? I'm not sure where the 'automatically' part comes in either.

Comment: I showed only 2 tables for example, but the script generate more than two tables, each time when script is runing, number of tables will be different...

I have any code, because i dont know, how to write dynamicaly joins...

i first case i get 3 tables, in second i get 4 tables, in third i get 10 tables...

Comment: You haven't posted what you've tried here. There's a suggestion of a solution below. If you need sample code, post your data as a data step and show what you've attempted to solve this issue.

Comment: I added a code that creates tables

Comment: Are you asking for help in fixing the original program to facilitate creating the combined data? Or just with dealing with the datasets that have already been created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use SQL for this?  It is very simple to merge multiple datasets using SAS code instead.  If you want to merge all datasets that start with `TableName_` you use the `:` wildcard to avoid typing the individual dataset names.

```
data want ;
  merge TableName_: ;
  by MT column RT AREA ;
run;
```

Why are you splitting the data into multiple tables to begin with?  Why not just generate all dates at once?

```
%macro sqlloop(start,end); 
PROC SQL; 
  CREATE TABLE DUPLICITY_BAL as 
    select 'ACCOUNTS' as MT
         , 'balance_lcy' as column
         , dt_rep
         , rec_type
         , area
         , sum(balance_lcy) as balance_lcy
         , count(balance_lcy) as count
    from database.ACCOUNTS
    where version_no = 1
      and dt_rep between &start and &end
    group by 1,2,3,4,5

    union all
    select 'C_ACCOUNTS' as MT
         , 'balance_lcy' as column
         , dt_rep
         , rec_type
         , area
         , sum(balance_lcy) as balance_lcy
         , count(balance_lcy) as count
    from database.C_ACCOUNTS
    where version_no = 1
      and dt_rep between &start and &end
    group by 1,2,3,4,5
  ;
quit;
%mend sqlloop;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer,
but i need for every day of the interval new column in table. If the interval contains 5 days, the table will be contains 10 columns of balance for each day. Not one balance column with a total value for all days together.

Comment: That is what adding the date variable as one of the group variable does. It makes a separated observation for each day. If you want to make a report with those rotated as columns use across variable in proc report. Or use proc transpose to make a table for reporting with multiple columns.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this in the first place, keep your data in a long format. Keeping the data long, means your table structure isn't constantly changing. Your reporting structure may change - but its easier from a DB perspective if the data is kept long. The wide format also violates the principle of 'Tidy Data'.

Append the tables and rename the balance_date to the balance, or something that's the same across all data sets.

If you want the wide form for reporting use PROC REPORT. If you really, really, really (and you shouldn't) want to store this in a wide format then you can transpose it AFTER using PROC TRANSPOSE with the ID and/or IDLABEL to create the same structure.